# LINQ eager loading | doesn't find method "include"

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make some eager loading with LINQ. The problem is that it doesn't recognize the method "Include"...

```
            var bbs = (from bbo in db.BuildByOffers
                   where bbo.offerID == offerID
                   select bbo.BuildingsBlock).Include("deliverable");
```

I added this namespace

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Produced compiler error:

> System.Linq.IQueryable' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**SOLUTION**
The query was is a method which was only returning a list of BuildingBlock.
My actual problem was that when I called this method and looped on the list, when I tried "Buildingblock.deliverable.description", It was not working.
I just did this

```
Deliverable deli = buildingblock.Deliverable;
deli.description;
```

I didn't explained my problem so good, sorry

Thx for your help !

Comment: What is the compile time error you get? Post the error message.

Comment: Error 4 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ProposalBuilderData.BuildingsBlock>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ProposalBuilderData.BuildingsBlock>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You didn't post the context code, but `BuildByOffer` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include is available to `ObjectQuery<T>` see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) msdn.

I would suggest you to apply Include method on dbset like below:

```
var bbs = (from bbo in db.BuildByOffers.Include("BuildingsBlock").Include("BuildingsBlock.deliverable")
               where bbo.offerID == offerID
               select bbo.BuildingsBlock)
```

Comment: Same error : "System.Data.Linq.Table<BuildByOffer> does not contain a definition for Include

Comment: I forgot to mention it. Yes I am

Comment: @Weedoze Post your Context class in question all answer here assumed you are using DbSet in the context but it seems you are not using DbSet.

Comment: If you mean explanation of the query. In buildByOffer, I got 2 Foreign Key and I Would like to get the building block and then in this building block, another foreign key to "deliverable"

Answer (score 2):

The `Include` method is defined on `DbQuery<T>` and as extension method of `IQueryable<T>`.

You need to import the `System.Data.Entity` namespace in order for the compiler to recognize that extension method.

**But...**

The real problem here that you're calling `Include` in the wrong place, you need to call `Include` on the source `DbSet<T>` before further projecting it:

```
var bbs = (from bbo in db.BuildByOffers.Include("deliverable")
           where bbo.offerID == offerID
           select bbo.BuildingsBlock);
```

Comment: System.data.entity is imported but still not working

Comment: Not sure... How can I check ?

Comment: Right click on your project and "Manage NuGet Packages", check for "EntityFramework" in the "Installed packages"  pane.

Comment: What is `db` in your code? Are you using Entity Framework at all?

Comment: SQL server database and I generate the C# classe via Entity Framework

Comment: haim770 is right. @weedoze No what you are using is called linq To SQL. You would have dbml file in your solution. it is not entity framework.

Comment: You need to install the `EntityFramework` NuGet package then make sure your context is indeed a Entity Framework context. If your models are created using the designer, you'll have to re-create them to have them working with EF.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `using System.Data.Objects;` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Project it to `IQueryable<T>` before calling `Include`. Like this:

```
var bbs = (from bbo in db.BuildByOffers
           where bbo.offerID == offerID
           select bbo.BuildingsBlock).AsQueryable().Include("deliverable");
```